# use '/\' to denote that one missed something while writing

Tags: typography, symbols

I have seen many people use '/\' to denote that they missed something while writing the sentence. Then, above that symbol they write what they missed. Are you aware of this practice?

Let's say, I am writing an exam (hand-written) where I have to write an essay and while writing the essay, I missed some words that I had to write. Rather than writing the whole sentence in full again, is it acceptable that I denote a '/\' between the words where I missed something and write the missing words above the symbol?

Is there any 'universally' accepted way of incorporating something that one missed while writing. Or start the sentence all over again?

Comment: Are you referring to handwriting? It's likely just a lazy arrow. A line would be used often too.

Comment: No, I am not referring to handwriting. I have seen this being followed by many of my classmates and I have also done that many times. Was curious if this practice is accepted around the world ;)

Comment: If it isn't handwriting why not just edit the sentence and insert the word you missed? I can't say I've ever seen anything like that used in printed text.

Comment: In printed text, we always have the option to edit whatever we wrote. But if the text is handwritten, can this practice be followed?

Comment: Can you do this on an exam? That would depend on how strict the professor is in grading it. They should definitely understand what it means, since it's a standard symbol for correcting galley proofs, but will they accept it? I'd guess probably, but there's no rule they have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the caret **^**, a proofreading symbol that indicates where something should be inserted.

[**caret ^**](https://www.csuchico.edu/style-guide/guidelines/copy-editing-marks.shtml)

> A caret shows where an additional or corrected or substituted letter, word, or phrase is to be inserted in or above the line.
> [image: "^p" correcting "apear" and "^comments" replacing "remarks". Caret is below line and the corrected text is above.]
> <sub>(California State University, Chico)</sub>